# jqgrid event when reload is finished?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using a jqgrid.

I can see how many rows I have like this:

```
$("#grid").getGridParam("records"));
```

I can reload some different data like this:

```
$('#grid').trigger("reloadGrid");
```

But once I trigger the reload how do I know when it is done loading and ready for me to see how many rows it has returned?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Handle the `gridComplete` event.

Answer (score 21):

Reload of jqGrid produce the same events as the grid load. So you can use the for example `loadComplete` which are the last event which execution after the grid loading (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#execution_order). So the code could be

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    // different parameters
    loadComplete: function(data) {
        alert ("records="+$("#grid").getGridParam("records"));
    },
    // different parameters
});
```

Comment: +1 for the link to the list of events! very useful. However, I ended up using the `gridComplete` event so I accepted Craig's answer. I am sure your solution is just as good, but I can only accept one. thanks!