# calling function after jqrid reload completes

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jq grid, and I want to call function when jq grid reload method is completed. How we able to

know that jq grid reload is completed?

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `loadComplete` event or `gridComplete` event.

There is a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3534568/1849444) by Oleg for your question.